# MVC Show different ValidationSummary ErrorMessage compared to ValidationMessage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

In ASP.NET MVC, is it possible to show a different message in the `ValidationSummary` compared to what is shown in the `ValidationMessage`?

IE - if i have a `FirstName` textbox, on validation the  message next to the text box will say 'You need to fill this out', but in the validation summary it will say 'Please provide a first name'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the Metadata available, I don't think what I want to do is possible. What I'm going to do instead is type in the input specific value for validation, and hide the class `field-validation-valid`.

Comment: What you are asking to do *is* possible and @ErikFunkenbusch provided you with an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you are trying to accomplish, but you can specify a generic error message in the validation summary. In your view you can use:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the errors below")
```

The boolean parameter indicates whether you want to exclude property errors. The string is the message you want displayed. Using this overload the way I have above, the model-level error message `Please correct the errors below` would be shown in place of the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` method, and the property errors would be shown where you place your `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` methods.

See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for a complete list of overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It should be quite obvious from looking at the intellisense.

you would say:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

and it will contain the error messages that are located on the model or the default messages

And you can say:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property, "This is a custom message")
```

And that overrides the message on the individual message.

Comment: Close - but "This is a custom message" will appear *regardless*. i want it to only appear as an error.. and i don't really want to put my validation messages in the views - i'd prefer to keep them in the metadata.

Comment: I assure you, the message only appears when there is an error.  You can read the documentation here.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703502(v=vs.108).aspx  My understanding of your question is unclear then, because, how do you expect to have two different messages if you don't want the message customized in the view?  You could just as easily have that message say "You need to fill this out" for every field.  The specific error will appear in the summary based on the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Also, keep in mind that @Html.ValidationSummary(true, 'Header Message') will show your custom summary message along with the same messages that you provided in your model data annotations.

i.e. in your model class:

```
[Required(Message="First name is required")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Your validation summary would look some like this:

**Header Message**

- First name is required

Alternatively, you can build up a custom collection of messages by using ModelState.AddModelError("Key", "Message") in your controller, then referencing that key in your view using ViewData.

Answer (score 0):

Providing different Errormesages beside the input fields and in the Validation Summary is not possible with @Html.ValidationSummary. Such a feature could make sense because a part of the errormessage's information can come from it's position in the page (e.g. beside a firstname input field the message could be 'Input required' and in the validation summary you need 'Input required for firstname'). Unfortunately a poor implementation for ValidationSummary in MVC, .net 2.0 provided the feature to have different messages in it's validators and in the validationsummary .